# JavaScript validating error

Tags: javascript

I finally figured out what makes the elements I’ve dubbed ‘folders’ to open and close. The issue is when I run the HTML document through the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/), it says attribute `<isfolder="true">` not allowed on `div` element at this point.

```
<p></p>
<div class="folderOpenClose" onclick="toggleAllFolders();">Open/Close Folders</div>
<p></p>
<div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);">Dice Roller</div>
<div id="folder0" class="folder" isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder1&#39;);">Slide Show</div>
<div id="folder1" class="folder" isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder2&#39;);">Carousel</div>
<div id="folder2" class="folder" isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="folderlabel" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder3&#39;);">Menu Bar</div>
<div id="folder3" class="folder" isfolder="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
<p></p>
```

The problem with me removing that is it what operates the Open/Close All and when I tried placing the code in the  form in the , the Open/Close folder doesn’t work.

```
    var lastChecked = null;            




function togglefolder(id){ 
    var ele = object(id);
    if(ele.style.display == 'none') ele.style.display='block';
    else ele.style.display = 'none';
}


function setAllFolders(how){
    var way = ""+how;
    if(way == "") way = "none";
    if(way == "closed") way = "none";
    if(way == "open") way = "block";

    var divs = window.document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++){

        if(divs[i].getAttribute('data-isfolder')&&divs[i].getAttribute('data-isfolder')=='true') 
            divs[i].style.display = way;

        var thisClass = ""+divs[i].getAttribute('class');

        if(thisClass=='folderlabel'){
            var thelabel = ""+divs[i].innerHTML;
            if(thelabel.indexOf('open/close all folders') != -1)
                divs[i].setAttribute('class','folderlabelopen');
        }
    }

    last_toggle=way;
}
```

Comment: Could you please pare your code down to the minimal amount you're asking about? Take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="folder2" class="folder" isfolder="true" style="display: none;"></div>
```

`isfolder` is not a known HTML property, so it is being flagged.

One solution is to use a `data-*` attribute such as:

```
<div id="folder2" class="folder" data-isfolder="true" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Then your code can use:

```
if(divs[i].getAttribute('data-isfolder') == 'true')
```

There is also a nifty [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) that you could use.

[More info on `data-*` properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: Sorry Jeremy. I placed the 'data' where you showed me and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you update all your references to `getAttribute`?  There are a number in your code.

Comment: Oh! Where do I do that? In the head or in the JavaScript code? I do apologize, but I didn't see that at first.

Comment: Apologies once again but where would I put it in the JS code?

Comment: replace all instances of `getAttribute('isfolder')` with `getAttribute('data-isfolder')`.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Just a reminder, since your new to the site, you might want to go ahead and accept my answer.

Comment: Hey Jeremy! I've clicked the checkmark. Though now I run into another problem. I've placed a lot of content between the 'folders' that have JavaScript and I don't know why. the JS files are attached correctly and they were working fine prior to me pasting them into the page with the 'folders.' The JavaScript codes and id's are correctly incorporated but the presentation won't work. And I don't think it's something with the scripting. Is there a way I can send you an attachment?

Comment: This is becoming a new question.  Reduce the problem down to something small enough to post here at SO and be sure to include any error messages from your console.   Make sure you've put the script at the **bottom** of the page.